# SQL sub-query: select all values but for one type of values only higher than

Tags: sql, subquery, extract

Is it possible to get all values for all currencies but for one particular currency only those that are higher than let's say 10000 USD?

```
select case
    when currency_id = '57' then 'EUR'
    when currency_id = '26' then 'USD'
    when currency_id = '51' then 'HKD' end as CCY,
    amount, ECPNBR, value_date
    from money_transfer
    where (select amount from money_transfer where currency_id ='26')>10000 order by amount desc;
```

this gets error that "subquery returns more than 1 value..."

Comment: I'd say maybe show some data and explain what is ECPBR? Most likely you are looking for a JOIN or correction in subquery.

Comment: Notice that you are missing a `from <table>` before where in your outer query.

Comment: ECPNBR is only an identification  number of payment. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe put your query like below

```
select 
 case
  when m.currency_id = '57' then 'EUR'
  when m.currency_id = '26' then 'USD'
  when m.currency_id = '51' then 'HKD'
  else '' 
 end,
 m.amount, m.ECPNBR, m.value_date
from money_transfer  where ( m.currency_id='26' and m.amount>10000) OR (m.currency_id<>'26')
order by m.amount desc;
```

Comment: may I know what table 't' is? I am querying data only from one table

Comment: how does your table store say 20USD in different currencies?

Comment: all currencies are stored in one same table, they differ by one column 'currency' which is filled in with case expression

Comment: @Tommeck37 OK. I think I have the right query now for you. Please see the answer. If it works, please do accept as answer and/or upvote